# C++ Arrays and Mathmatics

Tags: c++, arrays

```
 A={O|0<x<=10}
    B={E|0<x<=10}
    R={(a,b)a A, b B|a<b}
    A={2,4,6,8,10}
    B={1,3,5,7,9}
    AxB={(2,1)(2,3)(2,5)(2,7)(2,9) (4,1)(4,3)(4,5)(4,7)(4,9) (6,1)(6,3)(6,5)(6,7)(6,9) (8,1)(8,3)(8,5)(8,7)(8,9) (10,1)(10,3)(10,5)(10,7)(10,9)}
    R={(2,3)(2,5)(2,7)(2,9) )(4,5)(4,7)(4,9) )(6,7)(6,9) (8,9)}
```

Solve it using C++ program. You can use Arrays for storing the values and use nested for loop for finding the R(Relation). The above code is a Desecrate mathematics question and i want to solve it using C++.   i want to search from the arrays i write this code kindly guide me what is wrong in my code...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int a[5]= {2,4,6,8,10}, b[5]={1,3,5,7,9} ,R1[10],R2[10], counts =0;

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            if (a[i]<b[j])
            {
                R2[counts]= b[j];
                R1[counts]= a[i];
                counts++;   
            }
        }   
    }

    for(int i=0; i<counts; i++)
    {
        cout<<R2[i]<<endl;
        cout<<R1[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to find `AxB` ?

Comment: "kindly guide me what is wrong in my code" --> Are you getting an error message of some sort? Is it just the syntax `int main()` (you're missing an int but maybe on your computer it's different). Help us help you

Comment: I want to find R my code is giving wrong output

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<counts; i++)
{
    cout << "(" << R1[i] << "," << R2[i] << ")" << endl;
}
```